# Media Player Requirements in Android

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a media player application in Android. Its a bit of a lengthy explanation, but please go through it & suggest a solution

The application has a first screen that displays a list of radio stations. When the user clicks on any of these radio stations, the application goes to the second screen that displays the play, pause & stop controls. The activity in the second screen also initiates a service that prepares the Media Player & starts playing the media. Now I have two requirements

1. I want to show a progress status while the media has not started playing. It should be shown on top of the second screen & should disappear once the media has started playing. How do I do that? Is something is to be done in the Activity that started the service or in the Service itself?
2. Now when the media is playing, I want to go back to the first screen by pressing the back button(or may be exit the application). But the music should keep on playing unless I select some other radio station form the first screen(new music will start), or come back to the application from the notification panel & then stop the music.

Can someone suggest the best way to do this? Are there any sample codes available to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To show a status dialog, look into ProgressDialog called from your UI activity. To cause a service to continue playing, you need to use startService rather than bindService.

[Service lifecycle reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife)

Comment: Few questions here

If I show the ProgressDialog in the UI activity, how will I come to know when to dismiss it, since the music will play in the Service that I have created

Comment: Few questions here

1. If I show the ProgressDialog in the UI activity, how will I come to know when to dismiss it, since the music will play in the Service that I have created. How will my UI activity come to know that music has started. Is there a way for the UI activity to communicate with the Service
2. If I use startService, will I be able to use the play/pause controls from the UI activity to control the music? How will I communicate the Service to start/stop etc. Also, at some later point, if I need to stop the Service(when, user decided to play some other station), how will I do that?

Comment: You'll probably need to use AIDL if you don't use standard media player controls.

Comment: Didn't get you. I have to use standard media player controls. Am I doing something non-standard? Please help explain in more detail

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html. I really can't answer any more in depth without writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

For your second Question , i have solution . 
There are two ways to do it .

1. As you are telling create one Activity ,which shows play/pause media controls. And Respective Service will continue to play in Background.
2. Second way is that u can **initialize mediaplayer object** in your playing activity.Don't worry your mediaplayer will continue to play in background untill and unless it has not been **killed from task manager**. (**Mind it** , mediaplayer will continue to play music even if you are closing the activity)

For second way , make your both selection and playing activity **SingleInstance**

```
static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.radio_play_layout);

 //here check for one thing, **mediaplayer is null or not**. If mediaplayer is null than ur activity is **starting** and u need to have data from selection activity that i need to play this station & If your mediaplayer is not null than you are coming from **notification or widget** , put some IntExtra with pendingIntent to verify that you are actually starting activity from notification or widget.

  if(mediaplayer!=null && (getIntent.getIntExtra("verifier",0)==786)){

        //show ur currently playing stations details and control butttons.becaz activity is started from notification or widget.

  }else{

        //Initialize your mediaplayer , setlayout & startplaying 

  }
  }
```